# Windows command prompt cannot start

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-11, windows-terminal

When I run `cmd` in <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, Windows terminal starts, and instantly closes again. I do not have an AutoRun (checked registry and tried `cmd /d`). When I start an application that spawns a console, the application crashes as well.

I've tried both Windows Terminal and Windows Terminal preview. Both are set to go into WSL by default. When I start the Terminals directly, they sometimes crash, but do sometimes start correctly into WSL.

When the terminal *does* start, it works without any issues. I can open as many WSL and PowerShell tabs without it ever crashing. But as soon as I try to open a Command Prompt tab, it crashes again.

My Terminal config files (both are pretty much identical):

- Windows Terminal Preview config file: https://pastebin.com/NMhAXSwf
- Windows Terminal config file: https://pastebin.com/7LRUJ9D7

Update: When I successfully start Terminal as Administrator, PowerShell starts crashing also.

Another Update: I've uninstalled the Windows Terminal, and kept the Windows Terminal Preview. Now I have the old windows command line again. That works perfectly without any issues. As for the Windows Terminal:

I've noticed, that when I open a window, each window has a "stability" that it keeps.

- Some instances crash when entering the default WSL profile (not very stable)
- Some can load the default WSL profile, but be very unstable (crash when I change a setting in the settings tab for example)
- Some are **completely** stable, where I can open as many command prompt tabs as I want to without any problems whatsoever (very rare).

I'm pretty certain, that all the things listed above in the vain of "PowerShell works perfectly in unprivileged mode but not at all in privileged mode" were just coincidences in which I saw patterns

Is there maybe a crash log or anything that might point to where the issue is occuring?

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Post your Windows Terminal configure file.  This will indicate what your default profile looks like. We cannot help you without this information.  Please [edit] your question to include this vital necessary information

Comment: @Ramhound just added it to the post

Comment: Download, then update, then run the full scan of the free version of MalwareByte

Comment: Does your C: drive use BitLocker? If no, then are you using Windows Defender for antimalware? If yes, you could try an offline scan: [Run and review the results of a Microsoft Defender Offline scan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/microsoft-defender-offline).

Comment: An easy thing to try: open an Explorer window (Windows key + E), type `cmd` in the address bar (Alt + D to get there), and see if it opens a command prompt.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Opens up the terminal, that then crashes.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I am not using BitLocker. Ran a Malwarebytes scan, found something (was most likely a false positive, removed anyway) and rebooted. Problem persists

Comment: @XerneraC Have you performed the actions in [harrymc's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1829411/windows-command-prompt-cannot-start?noredirect=1#comment2884704_1829411)?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Ah yeah, sorry, Did both. Had some corrupt files that were repaired, rebooted, issue wasn't fixed.

Comment: @XerneraC 1) You may need to run them again until there are no errors found. 2) Does Task Manager still open (ctrl+shift+esc)? If not, the computer may be infected. 3) Is there anything showing in Event Viewer that gives a hint as to what is wrong (probably in the Application log if there is, but maybe in the System log)?